# How can I integrate wso2 identity with wso2 governance registry?

Tags: ldap, wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

How can I integrate wso2 governance registry with wso2 identity?
My identity is configured with LDAP. I couldn't find a tutorial on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `$GREG_HOME/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml` configration file. In the `UserStoreManager` section you will find `ConnectionURL` property which by default is pointing to the embedded LDAP of the WSO2 Governance Registry Server and looks like:

```
<Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}</Property>
```

Change this value to the corresponding LDAP URL of your Identity Server.

Comment: That depends on your project requirements. If you need a sophisticated security and identity management of enterprise web applications, services, and APIs then most likely [WSO2 Identity Server](http://wso2.com/products/identity-server/) is an answer to your common XACML dilemmas.

Comment: yes, here in the business have o wso2 identity, and i need integrate with wso2 governance registry.

Comment: Can you explain what is your use case? For the above mentioned use case you don't need an Identity Server, Governance Registry is enough for that.